# Gerund or infinitive what is better to use in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, difference, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

Can I say such a sentence? - TO BE an only child is a bit boring.
Or I have to say - BEING an only child is a bit boring?
Is there difference between them? Or if I use TO BE I must say - TO BE an only child IT is a bit boring? 
Thank you!

Comment: I agree with Hoda20a's Answer. However, only as a matter of word choice, I would say, "It's a bit dull to be an only child." I don't think I would use boring here.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no difference between them .
and for your last question i think it would be better to say : It is a bit boring to be an only child.